# Occational updating of JList on button press

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I was trying to update the contents of a JList when a button was pressed. So, I cleared the list model, then cleared the list and then proceeded to add new values to the list. Here is the stripped code:

**testList.java**

```
public class testList extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private Thread t;
    public DefaultListModel model;
    public boolean first = true;

    public testList() {
        model = new DefaultListModel();
        initComponents();
        this.centre(this);
    }

    public static void centre(javax.swing.JFrame f) {
        Dimension us = f.getSize(), them = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int newX = (them.width - us.width) / 2;
        int newY = (them.height - us.height) / 2;
        f.setLocation(newX, newY);
    }

    class updateList implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            tmp.getTheList();
            model.clear();
            ouputList.removeAll();

            for (int i = 0; i < tmp.returnList.size(); i++) {
                model.addElement(tmp.returnList.get(i));

            }
            if (first) {
                chList.setModel(model);
            }

        }
    }

    private void initComponents() {
    // generated by NetBeans 6.9
    }

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        t = new Thread(new updateList(), "List Updater");
        t.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        tmp = new aC();

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new chapList().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    static aC tmp;

    private javax.swing.JButton button;
    public static javax.swing.JList outputList;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
}
```

**ac.java**

```
public class aC extends testList {

    ArrayList returnList = new ArrayList();

    void getTheList() {
        returnList.clear();
        generateList();
    }

    void generateList() {
    // populate returnList with random values of random size using returnlist.add()
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when the list created for the first time, it updates the JList. When the button is pressed again, the JList only gets updated sometimes. And for further presses of the button nothing is displayed in the JList.

Could someone help me figure out what is causing this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: If you're allowed to, start your class names with capital letters.  This is a convention that most Java developers use, and so it makes it easier for many Java developers to read your code.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I will change the class names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your core problem is probably related to updating the Swing GUI from a thread that isn't the **[AWT-EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)**.

You might want to read about and/or look into using [**SwingWorker**](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) (shipped with Java 6 and also [available for download](https://swingworker.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList) for use with earlier versions of Java.)

Alternatively, have a look at this approach:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BackgroundWorkerFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public BackgroundWorkerFrame() {
        initComponents();
        jList.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
    }

    private void jButtonGoActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        Thread t = new Thread(new WorkerRunnable());
        t.start();
    }                                         

    public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Working hard...");
            sleep(1000);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                list.add((int) (Math.random() * 100));
            }
            System.out.println("Updating GUI...");
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new UpdateRunnable(list));
        }
    }

    public class UpdateRunnable implements Runnable {
        private final ArrayList<Integer> list;
        private UpdateRunnable(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
            this.list = list;
        }
        public void run() {
            DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) jList.getModel();
            model.clear();
            for (Integer i : list) {
                model.addElement(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButtonGo = new JButton();
        jScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        jList = new JList();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButtonGo.setText("Go");
        jButtonGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                jButtonGoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButtonGo, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        jScrollPane.setViewportView(jList);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-309)/2, (screenSize.height-338)/2, 309, 338);
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void sleep(long ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BackgroundWorkerFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    JButton jButtonGo;
    JList jList;
    JScrollPane jScrollPane;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: That is pretty close to what I intended. But,  I wanted to clear the existing list and display the newly generated list. I tried clearing the list, the model and the array list in your code, but could not successfully clear it. But, I really like the idea of calling another Swing Worker to do the UI updation though.

Comment: @Monk I updated the application to clear the list before populating new data.

Comment: Sorry. I just moved the model declaration above the loop and also cleared it. Works like butter. Thanks. I will try to implement in my code.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I updated my code by adding the new Swing Worker to update my GUI elements. Works Great.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you are doing is creating a new Thread and then making changes to your GUI component outside of the EventDispatchThread.  This is generally not a great idea.  Try running the `updateList()` in place, which will be on the EDT, as the button events are handled in that thread.

Comment: From what I have noticed, the list gets updated the first time. After this, the thread "List Updater" actually dies. It is only re-initiated after I press the button. So, the thread should work the same way as it did the first time. Also, if I understood you correctly, you are suggesting that I update the JList after the thread has died. If so, where should I place the code since the threads would be running simultaneously and I would be calling an empty array list. Thanks